# NASM 'fatal: No section for index 2 offset 0 found' on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, fatal-error

This is my first time programming in assembly for the Mac, and keep getting some strange errors that I haven't had much luck with googling-wise. So far, I'm just trying to print "Hello, World!" onto the terminal. Here is my code:

```
global _main


section .text

_main:
    mov rax, 0x20000004
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, msg.len
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x20000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data

msg:    db  "Hello, World!", 10
.len:   equ $ - msg
```

Whenever I run this code, I use the command `nasm -f macho64 print.asm`. By the way, `nasm -v` prints `NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Mar 10 2015`. When I use the command above, NASM gives this output:

```
print.asm:9: fatal: No section for index 2 offset 0 found
```

I'm stumped and would like any help. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you get line number 17, I get line number 9 (unless you didn't paste your actual file contents). Change `mov rsi, msg` to `lea rsi, [rel msg]`. You can't use absolute addresses like that.

Comment: @Jester Yeah sorry, I left out a comment. Edited!

Comment: Because it is not position independent and apparently macho64 requires that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the seemly problem. from [the](https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/7125822):

instead of :" mov rsi, msg", use: "lea rsi, [rel msg]"

Comment: I'm on 10.11, changing it to ` lea rsi, [rel msg]` doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @cubuspl42 same here. It seems to be a bug in nasm 2.11.x. Fixed it by downloading 2.10 http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10/macosx/

Comment: Anyone have a link to a bug report on this? i'm encountering this on 10.10 and 10.11 but not 10.9; would be nice to have an official upstream reference.